# WebSocket in Java Servlet (Tomcat 9) without classpath scanning

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I'm trying to set up WebSocket in Java Servlet (Tomcat 9) without classpath scanning, but I'm stuck with this error:

```
 javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to the same path [/test/{accountId}] : existing endpoint was [class probotdev.websocket.Test] and new endpoint is [class probotdev.websocket.Test]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:169)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:232)
```

Here's my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app version="3.0" metadata-complete="true" ...>
    <absolute-ordering/>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>probotdev.websocket.WebSocket</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
</web-app>
```

and the `WebSocket` class:

```
class WebSocket extends ServletContextListener {
    override def contextInitialized(sce: ServletContextEvent): Unit = {
        val container = sce.getServletContext.getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer").asInstanceOf[ServerContainer]

        container.addEndpoint(classOf[Test])
    }
}
```

and finally the `Test` class:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/test")
class Test {
    @OnOpen
    def onOpen(session: Session): Unit = {
        println("Bla!")
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `web.xml` is configured so that Tomcat doesn't scan the classpath (for servlets etc), but **it is still scanning WebSocket stuff**.

My solution? Just remove the `WebSocket extends ServletContextListener` class.